# Write shell script that can only be run by a sudo user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shell, scripting, sudo

I'm writing a shell script that is supposed to be run by users only in sudo user list, what's the appropriate way of doing this?

what I'm thinking is in the shell script, try to create a dummy file in system dir such as /var/run/ and remove it, so users not in sudo list will receive a permission error, but I believe there gotta be a more appropriate way of doing this, preferably detect if a user is in sudo list within the shell script. thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much simpler to do, just put the below at the beginning of your script

```
if [ `id -u` -ne 0]
then
    echo "Must be root"
    exit 1
fi
```

at the begining of the script.

Comment: @unknown (google) - Don't forget to check the permissions on the script file. If someone can edit the script, they can undo your work.

Answer (score 2):

Put the script in a directory that is only readable by root. That way users can't call it accidentally, or deliberately, or even read it to look for holes.

Answer (score 0):

when you run the script with `sudo`, `sudo` can check the group for you:

```
%yourgroup ALL=/your/command
```

when you put this in `/etc/sudoers`, `sudo` will check wether a user is in group yourgroup when the user executes `sudo /your/command`. this way you don't have to add a new user manually to the script.

Comment: That doesn't prevent anyone else from launching the script though, it just doesn't give them specific rights.